# Recent posts as thumbnails - want to show title below image

Tags: php, wordpress, thumbnails

I have found this code for showing thumbnails as recent posts in a widget. It appears in a grid format which I like very much. I would like to add the title of the post below each thumbnail images. I can manage to get the title show by using the_title(); but then it does not stay as a grid but turns into a list. I would appreciate any help. Thanks

The css used is:

```
.attachment-thumbnail {
height:150px;
width:150px;
padding:5px;
background:#fff;
margin:5px 5px 0 0;
}
```

Code:

```
<?php
$my_query = new WP_Query('showposts=12&amp;amp;amp;amp;orderby=rand');
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
?>

<?php
$attachments = get_posts( array(
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'number_posts' => 1,
'post_status' => null,
'post_parent' => $my_query->post->ID,
) );
if ($attachments) {
?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">

<?php
$thumbnail_id = $attachments[0]->ID;
echo wp_get_attachment_image( $thumbnail_id );
}
endwhile;
}
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It'd be helpful to know the CSS attributes that are being assigned to the title text when it's introduced to the page you're creating as that's likely what's turning your grid into a list.  I would think the best way forward here is to wrap the thumbnail/title pairs in a div and to make those divs have the attribute "display: inline" so that the divs appear side by side rather than on top of each other.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is the only css and the thumbnails show as a grid but as soon as I add the title, it becomes a list. I did try a div but I am not too good with all this.

    .attachment-thumbnail {
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
    padding:5px;
    background:#fff;
    margin:5px 5px 0 0;
    }

Comment: Phil, there has to be additional CSS at play here which you'll be able to change to get the effect you want. Have you tried looking at these elements with the code inspector in Chrome or with FireBug in Firefox?